# How do you present countries on your name card except from using text?

Tags: business-application, cards

I'm updating my company's name card, as we are expanding to other countries, we want to reflect those countries on our name card, but the problem I encounter is the map appeared very ugly, and we shouldn't simplify it as it will make some countries disappear.

What do you think?

**Update**: Thank you all for the useful tips, using country code is a good idea.

I think I should show the progress so that you guys can understand better.

First one simplified too much that removed some countries.
Second one is aesthetic-wise unacceptable, too complex for a small card

[![This one simplified too much that removed some countries.][1]][1]

[![This one is aesthetic-wise unacceptable, too complex for a small card][2]][2]

Comment: What's a Name card?

Comment: Name card as in business card, correct?

Comment: Yes, name card is business card.

Answer (score 2):

Use the country flag. You can simply place the country flags images(lets say of 32x32) at the bottom of name card and center align it.

Comment: What if someone does not recognise your country's flag?

Comment: You could use Alpha-2 or Alpha-3 codes, officially defined in ISO 3166-2 Standard. More informations here : https://www.wikiwand.com/en/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#/Officially_assigned_code_elements

Comment: @Brice yes nice. Actually I thought in question it is mentioned not to use text. Yeah nice one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Srija Yes I know, I was thinking to two characters used as monogram, maybe over the flag icon ?

Comment: @Brice yes that's a great idea.

Comment: Be careful overlaying text on an image. ISO country codes aren't always understandable either (ESP? NER? ISL?), and by placing them on top of flags, which are also not always recognizable, you're creating something that's, let's say, one sixteenth as clear. Simply showing the country's name as text is the most easy to understand, I'm afraid.

Comment: I agree with @KenMohnkern and avoid using flags as they can be controversial with some not being accepted or recognised by neighbours and other such political crap that you really don't want to get into

Comment: @Peter, besides that, how many people know flags? Not me - I couldn't identify Argentina or Poland or Saudi Arabia by their flags. Cover them with text and it's impossible.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful tips, using country code is a good idea.

I think I should show the progress so that you guys can understand better.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV06I.jpgThis one simplified too much that removed some countries.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rflzr.jpgThe other is aesthetic-wise unacceptable, too complex for a small card

Answer (score -1):

It is a small card, so I trust you want to keep it simple enough. And obviously a printed card means no popup or hover or tooltip. So, we need it to be in one layer and only one layer.

With that in mind, I will do a combination of flag and world map. Your first map is too simple, so much so that the borders are not proper. Considering you have locations mostly in Asia, you want borders to be a little better. It doesn't have to be perfect, just enough to keep the countries recognizable. See this link. https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-world-map_23-2147514300.jpg 
If this level of simplification works for your map, then select this. Keep the map as simple as possible while making sure that your locations are recognizable.

Second thing is flag. Instead of dots, you can add flags. That will help the location be a bit more recognizable. You can also do arrows for the location. Something like this. http://www.tiburondata.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/office-location1.jpg  Instead of names, you can use flag to save space.